# in SDL when i draw a menu over the screen it makes the game slower and doesn't work how can i fix this?

Tags: c++, sdl

HI I've been coding on sdl for a couple of months, i'm makin a little game to try, i can manage states, i have an intro screen a main screen with a play button and a game state,i load a map and drow to characters(entities) one that i control and another to make collision test, i can make the camera to focus on my character and follow him arroun the map, the problem is that i want to try in game menus(to give more speed,health,strenght to the character and things like that) so i made a new class tha renders a menu on the screen with an image that covers the whole screen and a button that closes the menu, but when i activate the menu (whit a key down event) the menu shows up but the button doesn't do anything and after a while the menu doesn't show anymore and the event that "creates the menu" doesn't work.

my code for drawing on the screen is this:

```
bool Draw::OnDraw(SDL_Surface* screen, SDL_Surface* image_draw, int x, int y)
{
    if(screen == NULL || image_draw == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    SDL_Rect drawing;

    drawing.x = x;
    drawing.y = y;

    SDL_BlitSurface(screen, NULL, image_draw, &drawing);

    return true;

}
```

also i create the screen with this:

```
if((screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF)) == NULL)
{
    return false;
}
```

I've tried SDL_Flip(screen) but nothing, i think the problem is to draw over the screen but what other way i could use to make a menu.
more code:

I'm activating the menu like this:

```
case SDLK_h: {
            hero_menu = true;
            break;
       }
```

on my render function i do this:

```
if(hero_menu)
    {
        MenuHero call_menu;
        call_menu.Activate_Menu(screen);
    }

void MenuHero::Activate_Menu(SDL_Surface* screen)
{
    menu_back = Draw::OnLoad("./image/hero_screen.png");
    close_button = Draw::OnLoad("./image/close.png");
    Draw::OnDraw(screen, menu_back, 0, 0);
```

**EDIT: 11/7/03**
I finally found my error, and was able to resolve it, however i have a new problem now, I'm calling my menu like this:

```
case SDLK_h: {
            MenuHero activate;
            activate.Activate_Menu();
            break;
        }
```

and in my Activate_Menu() Function from MenuHero class i have this:

```
void MenuHero::Activate_Menu()
{
    SDL_Surface* screen;
    menu_back = Draw::OnLoad("./image/hero_screen.png");
    Draw::OnDraw(screen, menu_back, 0, 0);
```

now it doesn't draw anything to the screen, i've been using SDL_Surface* screen in my whole code. am i not pointing to the screen? or screen in this scope is empty? how can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How slow is "slow"? You didn't specify numbers, so if it's [just a drop in your FPS](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/performance-why-did-i-just-lose-100-fps-by-drawing-one-trianglesprite-r3242), it can probably be ignored. Many people freak out when their speed drops a few hundred (!) FPS, not realizing that that measurement is actually a small amount.

How are you loading the images? Make sure you [convert them to an optimized format](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson02/index.php) for displaying. If you don't convert them when they're loaded, then *every single blit* SDL will have to manually convert *every single pixel*, and that can cause some real slowdowns.

(*Note: the first article I linked to is one I wrote and posted on GameDev.net. I'm not aware of any similar resources to link people to on that subject, and I don't get any benefit (financial or otherwise) from linking to it. The second I linked to wasn't written by me but is one I've found useful and helpful in the past*)

**Edit:**

Ah, there's your real slowdown (now that your original question was editted). You're accidentally (?) reloading your menu images from the harddrive every time you want to draw the menu. That's a very big slowdown, because accessing the harddrive is one of the slowest things computers do!

Or, at least that's what it *looks like* you are doing. But you're just posting tiny tiny snippets of code from a project, and it's not enough to know for sure. Programs are complicated things that have different parts of the code interact in intricate ways, so you're asking us to guess what word you are spelling, but hiding 90% of the letters in it. It's hard to debug and play hangman at the same time! =)

We need to see the intricate whole of all the related parts to solve your problem. These kinds of questions are better suited for community forums than Q&A sites, IMO.

**Edit 2:**
Your new problem is that if you declare a *new* "SDL_Surface *screen" local to a function, that's an entirely different pointer than any other variables that happen to be named "screen" elsewhere in your code.

Comment: actually i'm like 900 fps and gets down to 60, if you move the character it doesn't see like he is slow buth the thing is that the button doesn't work and after the menu gets hide or something the fps return to normal.

Comment: A decrease from 900 to 60 is the exact same decrease as a decrease from 60 to 30. (See the first linked article) It's much better to measure in millaseconds or microseconds.

Comment: Still, that is a bit slower than it should be. Are you optimizing your surfaces when you load them (see the second article I linked to)? Have you tried profiling to find the real slowdown? Also, your button not working is most likely unrelated to speed issues - could you upload your entire sourcecode somewhere, and link to it? Not enough code was given in the original post. Really, stack overflow isn't the best format for asking for help debugging programs, because SO is a Q&A site, but I digress.

Comment: @WilliamRottman Saw your new edit, added another edit to my post.

Comment: Np! We all need help with different parts of code. I'm banging my head over a problem myself in another SO thread. =)

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you are incorrectly initializing the `SDL_Rect` passed to `SDL_BlitSurface`. First you are assigning `x` to `drawing.y`, you probably meant to assign `y` to it.

```
SDL_Rect drawing;

drawing.x = x;
drawing.y = y;
```

There may be other problems but without seeing more code it's hard to tell.

Comment: Actually, SDL_BlitSurface doesn't need the width and height assigned on that specific rect, iirc. [documentation](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlblitsurface.html) Very nice catch of the mixed up X!

Comment: You're correct, only the `x` and `y` members of the rect are used for the blit.

Comment: It's not that it just i don't copy an paste the code and made a mistake while writing the function in here.